# Parsing different time formats with pydantic json_decoders not working as expected

Tags: python, datetime, format, iso, pydantic

Can somebody please explain me the behaviour of the following pydantic model.

```
from datetime import datetime
from pydantic import BaseModel

first_format = {'time': '2018-01-05T16:59:33+00:00',}
second_format = {'time': '2021-03-05T08:21:00.000Z',}

class TimeModel(BaseModel):
    time: datetime

    class Config:
        json_encoders = {
            datetime: lambda v: v.isoformat(),
        }
        json_decoders = {
            datetime: lambda v: datetime.fromisoformat(v),
        }

print(TimeModel.parse_obj(first_format))
print("first_format successfull")
print(TimeModel.parse_obj(second_format))
print("second_format successfull")
```

Output:

```
time=datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 5, 16, 59, 33, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
first_format successfull
time=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 5, 8, 21, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
second_format successfull
```

Expected behaviour:

Works on `first_format` as it does now, but fails at `second_format` as `datetime.fromisoformat(second_format)` throws an error for the wrong format

What I want to do:

Parse the time only if it has the format of `first_format`, else raise an exception.

Thanks for your help

Edit:
I later realized that there is no such thing as `json_decoders`, so please do not get confused by this

Problem resolved

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `pre` [`validator`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/) here, in order to parse and validate incoming datetime string:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

first_format = {'time': '2018-01-05T16:59:33+00:00',}
second_format = {'time': '2021-03-05T08:21:00.000Z',}


class TimeModel(BaseModel):
    time: datetime

    class Config:
        json_encoders = {
            datetime: lambda v: v.isoformat(),
        }

    @validator('time', pre=True)
    def time_validate(cls, v):
        return datetime.fromisoformat(v)


print(TimeModel.parse_obj(first_format).json())
print("first_format successfull")
print(TimeModel.parse_obj(second_format))
print("second_format successfull")
```

*Update*:

If you are using [pydantic v2](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.5/migration/) you need to use the [`field_validator`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.5/api/functional_validators/#pydantic.functional_validators.field_validator) instead since the `validator` was deprecated. The keyword argument is now `mode='before'`.

Comment: I realized later that there is no such thing as `json_decoders`, sorry for maybe confusing somebody with that